# Using the getFieldDecorator, how do I make sure that passwords contain lower case letters, upper case letters, and numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My react app uses Ant Design views. I am validating a form, but I am unable to validate the password to contain characters in lower and upper case.

I validated the following field with Ant Design:

```
                            <FormItem>
                                {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                                    rules: [{required: true, message: 'Please input your password!'}, {
                                    validator: this.validateToNextPassword,}],
                                })(
                                    <StyledInput placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
                                )}
                            </FormItem>
                            <FormItem>
                                {getFieldDecorator('Re-enterPassword', {
                                    rules: [{required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password!',}, {
                                    validator: this.compareToFirstPassword,}],
                                })(
                                    <StyledInput placeholder="Re-enter password" type="password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur}/>
                                )}
                            </FormItem>
```

Passwords are validated using the following functions:

```
handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
        }
        
        compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
            debugger;
            const form = this.props.form;
            if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password')) {
                callback('Two passwords that you enter is inconsistent!');
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        }
        
        validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
            debugger;
            const form = this.props.form;
            if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
                form.validateFields(['confirm'], { force: true });
            }
            callback();
        }
```

As part of this code, I validate whether the password field is empty or not and if the two passwords are similar. However, I also need to check that the password contains lowercase characters, uppercase characters, and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

`(?=.*[a-z])` - at least one small letter

`(?=.*[A-Z])` - at least one capital

`(?=.*\d)` - at least one digit

`[a-zA-Z\d]+` - only letters and digits allowed (defines the subset of allowed characters)

Answer (score 1):

Validator in your code only compares two passwords. You should add another one validator to `rules` array (it can receive any number of validators)

```
rules: [{...yourValidator}, { message: 'Password should contain uppercase letter etc'}, validator: this.strongValidator]
```

and write `strongValidator` function:

```
strongValidator = (rule, value, callback) => {
  if(!value.match(digitsRegex) || !value.match(uppercaseRegex)) {
    return callback(true)
  }
  callback()
}
```

Also you can option validateFirst to stop validating on first error

Comment: Thank you Artem, I already implemented a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

we can use regex in a format, which contains **at least a upper case,Lower case, symbol like (@$!%*#?&), min length and max length.**

here is the regex for min length 8 and other validation:

```
(([a-z A-Z 1-9 @$!%*#?&])(?=.*[A-Z][a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])).{7,}
```

here is the regex for  min length 8 ,max length 16 and other validation:

```
(([a-z A-Z 1-9 @$!%*#?&])(?=.*[A-Z][a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])).{7,15}
```